# bash read inputs (1 mandatory and 1 optional) and grep these two variables then redirect result

Tags: bash, shell, input, grep, arguments

read inputs (1 mandatory and 1 optional)

and grep these two variables from `abc.txt`
then redirect result to a new txt

```
read c d

while [ $# -ne 1 ]; do    #why -ne not -ge as grep c when there is at least 1 argument
        echo "Search result :"
        grep "$c" abc.txt
else grep "$c" "$d" abc.txt
break
done
```

Tried lots of times, will either take `c`, `d` as one argument or just ignore my `d` argument. Do I need to use shift in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please spend some time rewriting you questions so it makes sense and do something about the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`$#` is the number of command line arguments for your shell script. `read` doesn't change this value.

What you want is:

```
if [[ -z "$d" ]]; then
    # one argument
else 
    # two or more arguments
fi
```

Alternatively, you call your with the arguments on the command line (i.e. `./script c d`).
For this, replace `read c d` with:

```
c="$1"
shift
d="$*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${d+value_if_set}` to fill in a value to use when `$d` is present.

```
grep -e "$c" ${d+-e "$d"} abc.txt >new.txt
```

This adds a second `-e` argument after the first if `$d` is set.  So you end up running `grep -e "$c" -e "$d" abc.txt` in this scenario.

I have read (long ago) some advice against using multiple `-e` arguments to `grep` but it works with GNU `grep` and OSX (*BSD) `grep` at least.

Alternatively, you could use `grep -E` and modify the regex:

```
grep -E "$c${d+|$d}" abc.txt >new.txt
```

Here, the regex is either `$c` or `$c|$d`.  But you should note that the `-E` syntax also changes the semantics of what you put in `$c` and `$d`.